# Automatic Row And Column Adjustment

Tags: wpf, xaml

WPF :

Is there a way to make the width and height of rows (or columns) of a grid exactly fit to the dimensions of their contents?

---

EDIT :

> [Grid] in [Grid]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FF00AAE7" Foreground="White" Text="1" Height="30" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFF04937" Foreground="White" Text="2" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FF62BB46" Foreground="White" Text="3" Height="30" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

> [Grid] in [StackPanel]

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FF00AAE7" Foreground="White" Text="1" Height="90" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFF04937" Foreground="White" Text="2" Height="60" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FF62BB46" Foreground="White" Text="3" Height="30" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

**Note :**

In the second code, I changed the size of the first two textBlocks to highlight the automatic readjustment of the rows of the grid.

**Question :**

When no height is defined for the rows of a grid, why do they readjust automatically when the grid is inside a stackpanel and why do they not readjust when the grid is inside another grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just make Column `Width="auto"` and Row `Height="auto"`.

Something like:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
<Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Edit: Since your question has been modified.

In you first code snippet `Grid` by default will let its child take all available space if their is no width/height specified.

In the second code snippet, `StackPanel` stretches its child horizontally by default (note the `StackPanel.Orientation` is vertical here by default). The child (`Grid`) wants to take 180 vertical space which is the total height of all of its children (`TextBlock`s). In the end, `StackPanel` reserves 180 vertical space for its child.

You should read how WPF Panels layout their children. [Panel Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for ! I will edit my question to add an interesting detail that I have noticed.